# Is there any command line command/script to add a run script programmatically to an XCode project?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to add a run script to the build phase of an XCode project programmatically. I was able to narrow down to changing the project.pbxproj file as one solution. But is there a more cleaner way to achieve the same, maybe in the form of xcode commands (if such a thing exists!) or through a script?